# C++ assert() fails without giving any error message, or line where it failed

Tags: c++, c, assert

I am having a strange problem in my code. I have many asserts scattered around the code and all have been working fine. Whenever an assert failed I got a message giving me line number of where the failure happened.
  Today I wrote another assert in a function which loads a file. Just wanted to make sure that the fie existed. A very simple assert. Here is the relevant code:

```
//Check that the file exists and can be opened
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");

#ifdef ASSERTIONS_ON
    assert(f!=NULL);//@problem For some reason while all other asserts work, this one just crashes the program without reporting line
#else
    if(f  == NULL)
        return MODEL_LOAD_FILENOTFOUND;
#endif

fclose(f);
```

I know that this does not help a lot but just wanted to showcase what my problem is. My OS is Windows 7. The compiler is GCC. The error message I get from Windows is the usual runtime error but without line reporting:

"The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information"

What could be the problem? What can possibly cause an assert failure to just request termination without reporting a line where it happens, while in every other case in the same code it works as intended? Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have FUBAR'ed the stack somewhere before the assert executes.

Comment: Heck you are right...I did not know that messing up the the stack can lead to such assert behaviour. I just moved assert(0); around the place where I got the error, and found the offending function. Pretty nice. Thank you for your answer mate

Comment: I have one more additional question if you can answer it. This seems to have happened again to me. Now I am not able to pinpoint the reason. What kind of stack problems can lead to that? Is there any sure way to detect them? I am obviously doing something wrong

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this site's not really for a discussion about it and in fact IMO has poor message reply notifications, so you might have been better off making a second question. In any case, I'm not too familiar with GCC, but I'd start with setting a breakpoint somewhere you *know* is getting a corrupt stack and then backtracing while looking for code that'll kill the stack. This is actually easier than you think - if the code isn't in your current function and you can't follow the stack, then search through your code to find functions that call the function in which...

Comment: ...your current breakpoint is. Continue looking for code that breaks the stack. Being that you're probably a rookie (broken stack is so easily avoided IMO), I'll also mention that *some* evil libraries might be breaking your stack so make sure you check the stack before and after calls to library functions. That's most I can say without having access to your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well I am nowhere near a noobie but it is true that I have lost contact with the field for over a year. So I am going through the remembering process :)